# UTF8 encoding for letters šđžćč

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8, mysqli

i have a problem to display some letters (like šđžćč) on php page from mysql database. 
In my application I have a admin panel for inputting data in database. I use **mysqli** connection API to connect to the database. Short overview that I did to set UTF8 encoding are:

1. I set the database to utf8_unicode_ci charset;
2. I set all tables in my database to utf8_unicode_ci charset;
3. On page I set meta tag:

   ```
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
   ```
4. In my mysqli API I tried few codes for utf8 encoding, but nothing helps:

   ```
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");// first try


    if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {//second try
     printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
   } else {
     printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
   }


   mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");//third try
   ```

   Application was developed on localhost (xampp server), and on localhost works fine. When I upload the application on server, a problem with displaying data occurs. I contact the hosting company and told them about the problem, they have told me that everything is ok and that I must check the database (tables) using phpMyAdmin. They suggest me to edit data directly in the database. I did that and the displayed data was correct.

   But when I enter or edit data from my admin panel in application, I get the same mistake.

Comment: Check that all your admin panel scripts are saved as utf-8 as well. Since phpmyadmin can do it the problem is most likely in your scripts.

Comment: how does the output looked like. i had some problems with this myself and i managed to fix it. can you post how the output looks like???

Comment: The output for letters š đ ž ć č  is displayed as Å¡ Ä� Å¾ Ä� Ä�

Comment: my problem was a little bit different but this should help you...http://titanic.fauser.edu/php/function.utf8-decode.php.htm maybe double check if the table AND the columns in the table are ALL utf8.

Comment: Hi guys, I solved the problem, php sanitize function changed the characters. Thanks.